# Ext JS 4.2 Border Layout with IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, extjs4.2

I have a simple border layout with the following setup:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|         |                                              |
|  tree   |                 iframe                       |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
|         |                                              |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The whole thing is setup like this (obviously leaving out the minutia):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'border',
    height: 600,
    width: 1000,
    items: [
         {
             xtype: 'treepanel',
             (tree panel stuff here),
             region: 'west',
             split: true,
             width: 300,
             html: 'west panel'
         },
         {
             xtype: 'component',
             autoEl: {tag: 'iframe'},
             region: 'center',
             split: true
         }
    ],
    renderTo: 'content-div'

});
```

Here is a (simplistic) view of my html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>some stuff here....</div>
<div id='content-div'></div>
</body>
</head>
```

And here is my fiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qV7hs/)

What happens is when I try to drag the splitter bar to resize the width of the tree from left-to-right... I don't see the "shadow" of the splitter bar and it doesn't release when the mouse is unclicked. However, if I drop the splitter to the left, I can see the "shadow" of the splitter bar and it works just as expected.

I tested my theory by change from an iframe to any other type of component (panel, grid, etc) and it works just fine.

Has anyone seen this behavior and if so, is there an easy fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, I have seen it and no, it is not trivial to solve it. The problem is that the `iframe` is a new browser window so if mouse moves over it, it starts to receive events. In other words: mouse moves to the right go to iframe, to the left go to the main window.

If I would need to fix it, I would probably create a transparent `div` in the main window that would cover the iframe while dragging the splitter so that events can continue to be received by the main window.

Answer (score 2):

Following what [Saki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692525/saki) told, I find a workaround inserting a margin left equal to 5px.
It worked fine on Firefox, at least.

```
{

xtype: 'component',

margin: '0 0 0 5', // <-- New margin property

autoEl: {tag: 'iframe'},

region: 'center',

split: true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the splitter's tracker config to have tolerance of zero.

```
split: {
    size: 5,
    tracker: {
        tolerance: 0
    }
}
```

Tolerance controls the number of pixels the splitter must be moved before dragging is considered to have started.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter-cfg-tracker
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragTracker-cfg-tolerance